# $lim_{j->\infty} (j^j)/((j+1)^{j})$

Tags: calculus, limits

Can someone please explain this limit:

$$lim_{j\rightarrow\infty} \frac{j^{j}}{(j+1)^{j}}=\frac{1}{e}?$$

I got it from this series:

$$\sum_1^{\infty}\frac{j!}{j^j}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reciprocal is $\left(1+\frac1j\right)^j$, which is one of the definitions of $e$.

Comment: I know this limit but I don't see how to get there from where I am.

Comment: divide top and bottom by $j^j$ to get $\frac{j^j}{(j+1)^j}=\frac{1}{(1+1/j)^j}$

Comment: Ah, I see! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$$L=\lim_{j\rightarrow\infty} \frac{j^{j}}{(j+1)^{j}}=\lim_{j\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{(1+\frac1j)^{j}}$$

The limit is of the form $1^{\infty}$.

Thus,
$$L=e^{\lim_{j\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac1j}-1\right)j}=e^{-1}$$